# How to create a variable with value based on probabilities in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, probability

I have created a table called data. This table contains a non-unique ID field.

```
data <- data.frame(ID = sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T))
```

I have another table called probabilities, which contains matches for the ID field, corresponding ratios and names:

```
probabilities <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), ratio = c(0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0), name = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "F", "G", "B", "C", "G", "F"))
```

I am trying to create a new variable called name in the data table. This will be populated with the name variable from the probabilities table based on the ratio column.

For example, any ID of 1 in the data table should have a 90% chance of being A, and 10% chance of being B. An ID of 4 should have a 30% change of being B, a 30% chance of being C and a 40% chance of being G, and so on.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

I have tried the below but am getting an error:

```
#load packages
library(dplyr)


#create new variable called name
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(name = sample(probabilities$name[ID=probabilities$ID],
                       size = n(),
                       prop = probabilities$ratio[ID=probabilities$ID],
                       replace = TRUE))
```

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `name = sample(...)`.
Caused by error in `sample()`:
! unused argument (prop = probabilities$ratio[name = probabilities$name])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base R solution, using sapply() and sample():

```
data$name <- sapply( data$ID, function(ID) sample(x = probabilities[probabilities$ID==ID,"name"],prob = probabilities[probabilities$ID==ID,"ratio"],size = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your response! I'm getting the folowing error when I try to use this code: 
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
invalid first argument

Comment: weird, try to copy paste, and clean the enviroment, maybe some typo?.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `count()` your IDs, join the probability data, and use `reframe()` to sample by ID:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(ID = sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T))

data %>%
  count(ID) %>%
  left_join(probabilities, by = "ID") %>%
  reframe(name = sample(name, first(n), prob = ratio, replace = TRUE), .by = ID)

   ID name
1   1    A
2   2    C
3   2    C
4   3    F
5   4    B
6   4    C
7   4    B
8   4    G
9   5    F
10  5    F
```

To keep all vars, you can match the data back to the original order, and bind the result:

```
set.seed(99)
data <- data.frame(ID = sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T), other_var = 1:10)

data |> 
  count(ID) |> 
  left_join(probabilities, by = "ID") |> 
  reframe(name = sample(name, first(n), prob = ratio, replace = TRUE), .by = ID) %>%
  slice(pmatch(data$ID, ID)) %>%
  select(name) %>%
  bind_cols(data, .)

   ID other_var name
1   1         1    A
2   4         2    B
3   5         3    F
4   3         4    F
5   2         5    C
6   2         6    C
7   5         7    F
8   4         8    C
9   4         9    B
10  4        10    G
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. If I have other variables in "data" that I don't want to lose by using count(), can you think of another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

With a `data.table` non-equi join:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(969943335)

data <- data.frame(ID = sample(c(1:5), 10, replace = T))
probabilities <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), ratio = c(0.9, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0), name = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "F", "G", "B", "C", "G", "F"))

setDT(probabilities)[,cr := cumsum(ratio), ID][setDT(data)[,r := runif(.N)], .(ID, name), on = .(ID, cr > r), mult = "first"]
#>     ID name
#>  1:  1    A
#>  2:  5    F
#>  3:  1    A
#>  4:  4    B
#>  5:  1    A
#>  6:  2    A
#>  7:  5    F
#>  8:  1    A
#>  9:  1    B
#> 10:  5    F
```